# Increase the attribute length

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I have a custom attribute that is multi-select for a product along with 200 options.
When I tried to assign all the options. What I found is that there is the limit of 255 is it possible
to increase its length and its type to varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the type.

> 'type' => 'text'